# Difference between the libraries: Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid and Azure.Messaging.EventGrid

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventgrid

I have been trying to publish events to an Azure EventGrid using `Azure.Messaging.EventGridEvent.EventGridPublisherClient` and it works out just fine. I just discovered that there is another client for EventGrid, namely `Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid.EventGridClient`.

Upon investigation, both libraries and namespaces achieve the same thing, but expose vastly different methods and properties, and handle serialization and deserialization of `Data` very differently; while `Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid.EventGridEvent` directly exposes the `Data` property as a `public` property, `Azure.Messaging.EventGridEvent` has `Data` as an `internal` property and only exposes methods like `GetData<T>`, and `GetDataAsync<T>`.

Having two libraries do almost similar things has left me totally confused as to which one is the right library to use. Are there any guidelines as to when should we use one library over the other? Are there any benefits to using one over the other? I tried looking into the documentation but couldn't discern any information about the correct usage of either of these libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft is busy creating new packages for their Azure SDKs. Currently there are major differences in the way the Azure SDK packages work. To address this they have defined [new SDK design guidelines](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/dotnet_introduction.html) and they are in the process of replacing all Azure SDKs with new ones based on these guidelines.

The [Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid/) package is stable but is not following these new guidelines.  The [Azure.Messaging.EventGrid](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Messaging.EventGrid/) package is in preview but does follow the guidelines. Depending on your situation you might now want to use preview libraries. So you can stick to the stable one and replace it eventually if needed.